# YouTube video zoomed in Chrome browser. Right edge cut off in normal-screen. Bottom edge cut off in full-screen

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

So I was watching YouTube in my Chrome browser on my Mac, and I accidentally leaned on the left edge of my keyboard as I was pushing my chair away from the desk.

Now my YouTube video player window is "too small" for the video it contains.  The right edge of the video is cut off when I watch a video in "normal" mode, and the bottom edge is cut off when the video is in "full screen" mode.

Worse -- this setting seems to be tied to my Google Chrome browser and the account settings!  I deleted and re-installed Chrome on my Mac and the problem still exists.  I tried YouTube on my Windows PC, in a Chrome browser that's signed into the same account my Chrome browser is on my Mac, and the problem is there too!  Just to verify it's not tied to my YouTube account, I tried it in Safari, signed into my YouTube account, and the problem is NOT there.

So clearly I hit some kind of keyboard shortcut that "zoomed" in just the video-player window inside Chrome?  And saved it to my Google account, so all my Chrome browsers are now broken on YouTube?!

Comment: While this question was self-answered, I will migrate it to [su] because troubleshooting questions are off-topic in Web Applications, but they are on-topic in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- I finally figured this out after a bit of experimmentation.

Make sure the Chrome browser has focus (click somewhere in the browser window), then press Ctrl+Shift+1 (that's the number one), or Ctrl+Shift+2.  That will cause Chrome to zoom in and out in a weird way that doesn't show up on the Zoom control in the three-dots menu in the upper-right corner.  It will still show 100% Zoom, even though you're zoomed in (or out).

I have no idea what purpose this serves.  And it's tied to your Google account somehow, so it affects all your Chrome browsers on all your devices.  It will zoom in and out of ANY web-page, not just YouTube, but it has weird effects on YouTube that mess up video playback as I described.

Anyway, if your YouTube player in your Chrome browser is zoomed-in in a weird way, or ANY web=page you frequent is not fitting right, try Ctrl+Shift+1 and Ctrl+Shift+2 to zoom in and out to make it fit properly again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to a Google Chrome extension.

Extensions are synced across computers through the Google Accounts settings. Some extensions save the extension settings on the cloud, so they are synced across computers, too.

The above is because the keyboard shortcuts mentioned in your answer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, should be listed in the help articles about keyboard shortcuts for Chrome and YouTube.

To view the YouTube keyboard shortcuts, go to https://youtube.com and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>

To view the Chrome keyboard shortcuts, go to the help article [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en).

Next time, you can just reset Chrome instead of reinstalling Chrome when troubleshooting a problem like this. For details, see [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en). Still, before doing this, you might want to try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: Never occurred to me to try to disable my extensions to see if that fixed the problem. I was mystified as to why Ctrl+Shift+1 and Ctrl+Shift+2 weren't mentioned in any list of keyboard shortcuts for either Chrome or YouTube.  I just figured they were undocumented.  Thanks!